# Разработка приложения для android без java

Tags: android, мобильная-разработка

интересует один вопрос, могу ли я создать мобильное приложение в котором будет лишь интерфейс, а вся логика, базы и т.д. будут лежать на web сервере, подобно сайту, как бот Telegram. Я занимаюсь PHP разработкой, хорошие знания ООП, фреймворки, знания в js. Направьте в нужное русло, что я могу использовать? В идеале конечно кроссплатформенная разработка

Comment: Оно ведь так в любом случае и будет: шлете `get` и `post` запросы на сервер, получаете ответ, показываете результат. Вопрос в том, на чем вы хотите реализовывать интерфейс? Есть впринципе связка `ionic+angular` - подойдет для написания интерфейса на `html+js`, но сам его не пробовал.

Comment: ты хочешь приложку для андроида, веб средствами ? посмотри о react-native или PhoneGap

Comment: да, интересует web средствами, с возможностью авторизации и отправки запросов/получения ответа

Comment: я свой pet-проект делаю на asp.net webApi(бєк) + react-native(фронт), пока проблем и трудностей не возникало, все просто, если нужны какие-то нативные штуки, типа включить вай-фай или камеру, есть сторонние либы для каждого случая, производительность то же не храмает

Comment: А каким образом может быть реализована авторизация? Я так понял, что за "сервер" может сойти yii приложение, верно?

Comment: [Тут](http://infoshell.ru/blog/start-v-android-programmirovanii/) найдете мануал о старте в android-программировании.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы вам советовал посмотреть:

- Самый хайповый: **React Native** (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/)
- Пытающийся взлететь: **Flutter** (https://flutter.io/)
- Подающий надежды, но еще не вышедший в люди: **Progressive Web Apps** (https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/)

Все выше современные кроссплатформенные решения основанные на принципах Web-разработки.

Comment: Стоит отметить, что Flutter использует Dart, мало кто [пока] его знает. И  Cordova наверное нужно добавить

Comment: Cordova такая древняя, я бы уже вместо нее Progressive Web Apps начал изучать. Поэтому и не добавил.